# Haskell "show is applied to too many type arguments"

Tags: haskell

I am trying to replicate the UNIX program wc in haskell. To make this easier I have created a type:

```
data WCResult = WCResult {
                      wordCount :: Int,
                      fileName  :: String
                     } --deriving (Show)

instance Show (WCResult x y) where
    show (WCResult x y) = show x ++ " " ++ y
```

When I try and run this program I get

```
wc.hs:9:15:
`WCResult' is applied to too many type arguments
In the instance declaration for `Show (WCResult x y)'
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The type `WCResult` doesn’t take any parameters — you’re confusing the *type* constructor with the *data* constructor, which does take arguments:

```
instance Show WCResult where
    show (WCResult x y) = show x ++ " " ++ y
```